# Best algorithm to calculate the integer partition number

Tags: complexity-theory

The total number of ways a positive number $n$ can be partitioned is called the partition number $p(n)$. The best algorithm I found on the internet is a dynamic programming implementation of Euler's pentagonal formula. Is there any proof that there cannot be any better algorithm? Is there any better algorithm already?

Answer (score 4):

Fredrik Johansson showed in his work [Efficient implementation of the
Hardy-Ramanujan-Rademacher formula](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.5991.pdf) how to compute $p(n)$ in time $O(\sqrt{n} \log^{4+o(1)} n)$ (the recent optimal integer multiplication algorithm might result in a removal of the $\log^{o(1)} n$ factor). This is nearly optimal, since the output length is $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$.